# Fetch robot framework results from outside

Tags: user-interface, robotframework

I want to run robot scripts from my own GUI(web page which i'm creating)when i click run it should start robot script execution at the background so to do this i want to know is there any Plugins or APIs in robot framework and also how to fetch results of robot scripts from outside 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The first result I get on google for a search for "robot framework API" provides a link to this page: https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/.

I don't know what you mean by "fetch results of robot scripts from outside". "outside" is a vague term. When robot runs, it generates a file named output.xml (unless you give it a different name). This xml file contains the results of the test run.

Results as the test is running can be obtained by using the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface).

Comment: what i meant from "outside" is remote system. I could not find anything related to feasibility of my requirements so i thought to ask here, my requirement is i want to start the robot scripts and fetch corresponding results from GUI(which i'm creating) i want to know is this feasible or not (if feasible what is est way to follow)??

Comment: @SuhasLalige: if you want the results while the test is running, use the listener interface. You can use it to write results to a database or a temporary file. If you want them after it's done, read and parse the output file that robot generates.